# Salesforce Custom Object: Invalid Type error Speaker

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am new in salesforce I tried to execute the Apex code in the developer console.

I have a created one object called **Speaker** with few fields. I am trying to execute the below code but it is giving me an error after executing the code.

```
Line: 1, Column: 1
Invalid type: Speaker
```

I am not able to understand these error, I tried to give permission to read/write/edit/delete to the object from the profile, but it is not resolved.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Custom objects in Salesforce are postfixed with `__c` in their API names. You'll need to refer to this object as `Speaker__c`.

The complete API names of any object or field are available in Object Manager in Lightning Setup. Note that additionally, to interact with the object or field in Anonymous Apex, your Profile must have the appropriate access to the object or field in Field-Level Security.